# C# IndexOf, when word is part of another word, How to?

Tags: c#, string

let's say I have **string** `"soak oak"` and I want to have string `index` of (`"oak"`), it returns me the index of where `"oak"` starts in `"soak"` (**1**) but I want to find index of exact word `"oak"` (**5**), what do I need to do?

```
string text = "soak oak";
char[] seperators = {' ', '.', ',', '!', '?', ':',
        ';', '(', ')', '\t', '\r', '\n', '"', '„', '“'};
string[] parts = text.Split(seperators,
                        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
text.IndexOf("oak"); // gets '1' because "oak" is in "soak"
                     // but I want to get 5 because of exact word "oak"
```

Comment: You are searching inside the string `text` instead of the string[] `parts`.

Comment: you're most of the way there... You've split the text by separators into parts. Now you just need to check if any of those parts are exactly "oak"

Comment: You need to implement an algorithm for it.Step 1. Push all characters into an array, Step 2. Check first letter of the array or letter after a space is starting with the keyword you are looking for. step 3: On start letter char match, loop for consecutive char to match the rest of the keywords. step 4: if all char match found then the first char index is your required ANSWER!!

Comment: You could make use of the System.Text.RegularExpression namespace.  Here is an example of matching a whole word using Regex: https://regex101.com/r/7ijsEh/1 .  You can then use Regex.Match(text, "\boak\b").Index.    See here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/94XDQb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can test indexes (`IndexOf`) in a *loop*:

```
static HashSet<char> s_Separtors = new HashSet<char>() {
  ' ', '.', ',', '!', '?', ':', ';', '(', ')', '\t', '\r', '\n', '"', '„', '“'
};

private static int WordIndexOf(string source, string toFind) {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(source) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(toFind))
    return -1;

  for (int index = source.IndexOf(toFind); 
       index >= 0; 
       index = source.IndexOf(toFind, index + 1)) {
    if (index < 0)
      return -1;

    if ((index == 0 || s_Separtors.Contains(source[index - 1])) &&
        (index >= source.Length - toFind.Length || 
         s_Separtors.Contains(source[index + toFind.Length])))
      return index;
  }

  return -1;
}
```

Demo:

```
// 5
Console.Write(WordIndexOf("soak oak", "oak"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Regex approach

```
string text = "soak oak";
int result = Regex.Match(text, @"\boak\b").Index;
```

Comment: or you could use "\boak\b", which looks for word boundaries

Comment: string text = "soak oak";
    var match = Regex.Match(text, @"\s[oak]");
    if (match.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(match.Index); // 4
    }

Comment: `string text = "I can see an\toak."` Expected: **13**, actual: **0**

Comment: @RobinBennett thanks, I've updated my code to your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You may use below regex to find exact word in your string.

```
string text = "soak oak";
string searchText = "oak";
var index = Regex.Match(text, @"\b" + Regex.Escape(searchText) + @"\b").Index;
```

**Output:**

```
5
```

See the [**demo**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/u0Ytbg)

Comment: `@"\b" + Regex.Escape(searchText) + @"\b"` to be on the safe side

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, thanks for improvement, answer updated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can  use regular expressions, you may also find it useful to use word boundaries defined by regular expressions:

```
string text = "soak oak";
var pattern = @"\boak\b";
var regex = new Regex(pattern);
foreach(Match m in regex.Matches(text)){
    Console.WriteLine(m.Index);
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could find the string in your array by converting it to a list and using the IndexOf() method.

```
parts.ToList().IndexOf("oak");
```

That tells you which array item it is, rather than the index in the original string.

Answer (score 0):

Another RegEx approach-

```
    string text = "soak oak";
    var match = Regex.Match(text, @"\s[oak]");
    if (match.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(match.Index); // 4
    }
```

- \s *White space*

Hope it helps.

Comment: `[oak]` is inccorect here: counter example is `"a kao is not an oak"`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Yes, you are correct. Thanks. How about this though, @"\s(oak)"?

Comment: `"oak"` is a counter example for `@"\s(oak)"`: we don't want explicit `\s` in the pattern; please, have a look at *er-shoaib's* answer